# Can't make a request to closed comm Python Spyder IDE error

Tags: python, anaconda, nsight

Has anyone had this problem before? I get the below error message when I try to run a Python script in Spyder IDE while using NVIDIA Nsight Systems.

> CommError: Can't make a request to a closed comm

Answer (score 3):

Apparently the restart kernel functionality doesn't work properly. You can stop that kernel and open up a new console, this triggers the init of a new kernel without restart the whole program (Spyder 4)

Answer (score 2):

Does this error occurs when trying to generate plots? If so, I was also in such a situation and this works for me:

1. Preference > IPython console > Graphic: Check "Graphic Backend" is set to Automatic
2. View > Panes > Plots: Check that "Mute inline plotting" is checked and view your plots using this pane afterward.

Comment: Update: I don't get this error when plotting now. However, I also got this error when producing gigantic arrays (Using VScode it stops running at that point as well). This might be another reason...

Answer (score 1):

Yep. Same here with Spyder 4.0. Downgrading to 3.3.6 resolves.

Answer (score 1):

Restart the spyder app and run the program. This worked out for me